# Imprimir un rombo con asteriscos de ancho n (con n impar)

Tags: python

me dan un número n y tengo que crear un rombo de ese ancho n. Tengo la parte de arriba del rombo pero me falta la de abajo y no sé como anotar el código. Llevo esto:

```py
n = int(input())
for i in range (((n-1)//2)+1):

    fila = (((n-1)//2)-i) * " " + ((2*i)+1) * "*" + (((n-1)//2)-i) * " "

    print(fila)

for j in range (((n-1)//2)+1, (n-1)+1):

    fila2 = ((n-1//2)-j) * " " + ((2*j)+1) * "*" + ((n-1//2)-j) * " "

    print(fila2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pasa esto con el código que me dieron abajo:

[image: Pasa esto con el código que me dieron abajo]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé muy bien si es lo que buscas. Si no es lo que buscas hazmelo saber y trataré de corregirlo

```
def dibujo_rombo(valor):
  """

  for i in range(1, valor + 1) -> Creamos un bucle entre el 1 y el valor introducido por el usuario

  " " * (n - i) -> Añadimos los espacios al inicio

  "*" *(i + i - 1) -> Cada valor entre el rango 1 y n + 1, retornamos la cantidad de asteriscos

  [] -> El resultado lo retorna dentro de una lista. Tipo list de Python

  "\n".join() -> Dividimos el array en una cadena separando cada elemento con un \n (salto de linea). La barra invertida que está antes de la 'n' se usa para escapar caracteres

  """

  result1 = [" " * (valor - i) + "*" * (i + i - 1) for i in range(1, valor + 1)]

  return "\n".join(result1 + list(reversed(result1[:-1])))

# Llamada al método y entrada de datos       
entrada_numero = int(input("Introduzca un número: "))

print(dibujo_rombo(entrada_numero))
```

Comment: Es muy similar a lo que busco, pero en este caso el rombo sale más "largo" y "ancho". Necesito que por ejemplo, en el caso de ser n=5, los asteriscos de la fila de al medio sean 5, como se ve en la foto.

Answer (score 1):

Para un ancho 5 necesitamos los siguientes series:

```
- número de espacios:                          2  1  0  1  2
- número de asteriscos:                        1  3  5  3  1
- variable i de -n+1 hasta n-1 en pasos de 2: -4 -2  0  2  4
- valor absoluto de i (abs(i)):                4  2  0  2  4
- n-abs(i):                                    1  3  5  3  1      
- abs(i)//2:                                   2  1  0  1  2
```

En código:

```py
n = 5
for i in range(-n + 1, n, 2):
    print(" " * abs(i // 2) + "*" * (n - abs(i)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar el rombo n debe ser impar, aquí tengo una posible solución a lo que necesitas
hay que hacer mas validaciones pero esta es la idea principal.

```
n = int(input("Ingrese un número entero positivo impar"))

if n % 2 == 0:
    n += 1
sim = "*"

for x in range(1, n+1, 2):
    print("{:^33}".format(x * sim))
for j in range(n-2, 1, -2):
    print("{:^33}".format(j * sim))
print("{:^33}".format("*"))
```

Comment: Empleando `for j in range(n-2, 0, -2):` no hace falta la última linea aparte.

Comment: También  se podria hacer con un solo bucle: `for x in list(range(1, n + 1, 2)) + list(range(n - 2, 0, -2)):  print("{:^33}".format(x * sim))`